# MySql Insert Query Error: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to use a query to insert some log data in my database that i will need later when someone change his password but i couldn't add the insert query i always get this error in the title here is my code

```
$oldpw = $_POST['oldpw'];
$newpwd = $_POST['newpwd'];
$newpwd2 = $_POST['newpwd2'];
$username = LoggedUser()['Username'];
$qvars = [':User'=>$username,':oldpw'=>md5($oldpw)];
$qvars[':pass'] = md5($newpwd);
    $insertuser = query("insert into SRO_VT_WEBSITE..TB_User (StrUserID,encrypted_password,old_password,new_password) values (:User,:oldpw,'$oldpw','$newpwd')", $qvars);
```

and this is the code of the conn file and the "query" function inside of it

```
function Open($host, $user, $pass, $acc, $shd, $log)
{
global $conn;
global $array;
global $_allowSecretCode;
global $_secretCodeColumn;

 $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$host;database=$acc", $user, $pass,[PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT=>5]);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$array[] = $host;
$array[] = $user;
$array[] = $pass;
$array[] = $acc;
$array[] = $shd;
$array[] = $log;

if ($_allowSecretCode && !ColExist($_secretCodeColumn, "TB_User", $array[3]))
    $_allowSecretCode = false;
}

/* Execute a Query */
function query($query, array $args)
{
try {
    global $conn;
    $q = $conn->prepare($query);
    $q->execute($args);
    //_log("db.log", "QueryExecuted: " . $query . "\n"); logging
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    HandleException($e, $query);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    HandleException($e, $query);
}
return $q;
}
```

Comment: I really recommand you to do this with a trigger.

Comment: Please stop using MD5. Remove `,'$oldpw','$newpwd'`.

Comment: @ArnaudPeralta how to do that sorry :)

Comment: @user3783243 MD5 is necessary to my data here the pw should be enc, i also removed $oldpw & $newpwd same problem

Comment: It is unclear how the two code blocks relate. Please revise. Also, why are you parameterizing some values but not all (i.e., `:User,:oldpw,'$oldpw','$newpwd'`)?

Comment: `Password=:pass , phone = '$newpwd' where StrUserID=:User`, and qvars contains `[':User'=>$username,':oldpw'=>md5($oldpw), ':pass'] => md5($newpwd)];`. Of course it's not going to match.

Comment: Also, your insert query would fail because you're passing 4 values into 6 columns.

Comment: @Parfait i only need those four values as a test

Comment: @aynber the update query is working just fine the problem is in the insert query check the post again i edited the query sorry i wrote it wrong

Comment: The same thing applies. You have 2 placeholders in the query, but passing 3 in the array.

Comment: @aynber so i need to call all of the array column to make a success insert query ?

Comment: You need to pass in only what you need. If you have 2 placeholders in your query, then your array needs to be only those 2 placeholder pairs. If you have 4 placeholders, then only those 4 pairs. Also, it's not a good idea to mix placeholders and values like that. Change the old/new password variables to placeholders, and pass them into the array as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your query parameters here:

```
$q = $conn->prepare($query);
    $q->execute($args);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: i got "undefined variable args"
the function is in another file as i mentioned
i changed the query to
            $query = "insert into SRO_VT_WEBSITE..TB_User (StrUserID,encrypted_password,old_password,new_password) values (:User,:oldpw,'$oldpw','$newpwd')";
    $q = $conn->prepare($query);
     $q->execute($args);